# How to split a string without losing any word in Java?

Tags: java, string, split

I was using eclipse for Java.

I want to split an input line without losing any char.

For example input line is:

```
MAC 4 USD7MAIR 2014 USD1111IMAC 123 USD232MPRO 2-0-1-5
```

And the output should be:

```
MAC 4 USD7,MAIR 2014 USD1111,IMAC 123 USD232,MPRO 2-0-1-5
```

(If I split with `"M"` or etc. the char `M` itself will be removed.)

What should I do?

Comment: What rule you apply to split from `USD1111IMAC` to `USD1111,IMAC`?

Comment: i just want to split like that:
MAC 4 USD7,
MAIR 2014 USD1111,
IMAC 123 USD232,
MPRO 2-0-1-5

Comment: How comes `I` in the second part?

Comment: when i using split("\\I")  then my IMAC become MAC = =

Comment: So actually you want to split **after** the `USD\d+`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj , yup ~the difficult part is the second part

Comment: @weston, basically yes, because the price stick with the product name, but when i using \d+ , also will split the year number.

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a positive lookahead.

```
string.split("(?=M)");
```

OR

```
string.split("(?<!^)(?=M)");
```

**Example:**

```
String totalString = "MAC 4 USD7MAIR 2014 USD1111IMAC 123 USD232MPRO 2-0-1-5";
String[] parts = totalString.split("(?=M)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[MAC 4 USD7, MAIR 2014 USD1111I, MAC 123 USD232, MPRO 2-0-1-5]
```

**Update:**

The below regex would split the input according to the boundary which exists immediate after to `USD\d+`, `\d+` here means one or more digits.

```
String totalString = "MAC 4 USD7MAIR 2014 USD1111IMAC 123 USD232MPRO 2-0-1-5";
String[] parts = totalString.split("(?<=\\bUSD\\d{1,99}+)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[MAC 4 USD7, MAIR 2014 USD1111, IMAC 123 USD232, MPRO 2-0-1-5]
```

`(?<=...)` called positive look-behind assertion. In languages which support variable length lookbehind (`C#`), you could use `(?<=\\bUSD\\d+)`. But unfortunately java won't support variable length lookbehind. So we define the digits   like allow `\d{1,99}` digits from 1 to 99 means lookafter to the `USD`+digits upto `99`. And the `+` after the `}` called possessive quantifier which won't let the regex engine to backtrack, thus matching the largest possible value.

Comment: Can I ask the difference between the two?

Comment: Won't get his desired output. His desired output doesn't make sense though.

Comment: @KevinPaton in other languages like php you split according to something take `M` against this `MfooMbar`, it would create an empty element at the start, since splitting is also done on the boundary which exists before the first `M` . So to make the regex not to match the boundary which exists before the first `M` (at the start), we need to use negative lookbehind or negative lookahead. But i think java by default removes the empty string from the returned list.

Comment: @AvinashRaj   awesome!! it is work!!  can i know what is this mean (?<=\\bUSD\\d{1,99}+)

Comment: So this matches USD to 99 decimals, I know apples are pricey but that's a tad pessimistic!